# NAnt extension function, Project object

Tags: c#, nant

Is there a way to access the `Project` object from a NAnt extension function, as can be done from an extension task?

In this example, I want to use the `BaseDirectory` property inside the `Bar` function:

```
[FunctionSet("foo", "Foo")]
public class FooFunctions : FunctionSetBase
{
    public FooFunctions(Project project, PropertyDictionary properties)
        : base(project, properties)
    {
        // When does this constructor gets called?
    }

    [Function("bar")]
    public static string Bar(string name)
    {
        return "Bar!"; // How to get at project.BaseDirectory?
    }
}
```

I'm new to NAnt extensions, so I don't know if this is even a valid question or if I should approach the problem differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question Tom. The abstract base class, **FunctionSetBase**, has a property called **Project** that you can access from the **Bar** function. However, I noticed that the Bar function is declared static, which is not always necessary (but not wrong).

The following should be completely legal in NAnt world:

```
Function("bar")]
public string Bar(string name)
{
    string baseDirectory = Project.BaseDirectory;
    return baseDirectory; 
}
```

Are you seeing any problems?

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks! For anyone interested: The constructor for FooFunctions is called on each invocation of the (non-static) Bar method.